# Trigger update one table after another table is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to write trigger which update table X after table Y is updated.

I tried to search the web and to write some code but nothing.

Currently my code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Update_YCR_Status
ON dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Transactions
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE  dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Requests
    SET YellowCard_Status = 

END
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want the value to be for Status in your Update statement?  And which RDBMS?

Comment: How are we supposed to guess with what value you want to update that column?

Comment: I want to update the fienld "YellowCard_Status" with the value of the updated row on table dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Transactions, column: "YellowCard_Status".
SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. You just create a trigger on table Y and issue an `UPDATE` statement against table X, like you have above.

In SQL Server, if you want to base the new value in table X on a value that was just inserted, you can reference the `inserted` table, which represents the data being added or updated.* For example:

```
UPDATE requests
SET requests.YellowCard_Status = inserted.YellowCard_Status 
FROM dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Requests requests 
JOIN inserted ON requests.FieldName = inserted.FieldName
```

I know you can do this in SQL Server. I'm not sure if this applies to other RDBMS's or not.

*For an `INSERT` statement, the inserted table contains any new rows. For an `UPDATE` statement, there will be a `deleted` table which contains the old data and an `inserted` table which contains the new data as a result of the update.

Comment: Hi, i don't get why i need the Join here?

i wrote this:
 UPDATE  dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Requests
 SET YellowCard_Status = inserted.YellowCard_Status
 FROM dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Transactions
 JOIN inserted ON dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Requests.YellowCard_Status = inserted.YellowCard_Status

but i get error:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_Update_YCR_Status, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "inserted.YellowCard_Status" could not be bound.

Comment: You don't want to join on YellowCard_Status, you want to join on whatever field links `tbl_YellowCard_Transactions` and `dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Requests`. The reason for the join is that triggers should always be written to handle multiple-row updates or inserts, so we need to make sure that the proper rows are being updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Finally i wrote this:
 UPDATE requests
 SET YellowCard_Status = inserted.YellowCard_Status
 FROM dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Requests requests
 WHERE YellowCard_Request_ID = inserted.YellowCard_Request_ID
 JOIN inserted ON requests.YellowCard_Request_ID = inserted.YellowCard_Request_ID

but i get an arror on the Join row

Comment: Try this: `UPDATE requests SET requests.YellowCard_Status = inserted.YellowCard_Status FROM dbo.tbl_YellowCard_Requests requests JOIN inserted ON requests.YellowCard_Request_ID = inserted.YellowCard_Request_ID`

Comment: it passing compilation, i'll test it now, it should work, thanks :-)